# Send an upd packet to local Datagram Socket of windows store API

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, windows-runtime, typescript

I have a strange problem in my development virtual machine. I open a Datagram socket of windows store API in this way (TypeScript):

```
this.winrtSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket();    
this.winrtSocket.bindServiceNameAsync(port.toString()).done(() => {
done();
}, (errorinfos) => {
error(errorinfos.toString());
});
```

It is possible to send an UDP packet to this socket from outside the VM. It is possible to send an UDP packet from inside these app after connecting to. But it is NOT possible to send an UPD packet from any other application in the VM.

First I thought it is a driver or VM problem. But I tested local udp commincation with netcat and other UDP diagnostic tools. It works fine.

Any idea what's wrong here? My App should receive UDP packets from device and from other devices.

best regards

Comment: Are you talking about only WinRt apps? They can't communicate to localhost without extra security and side loading. (It's only supported for Enterprise apps). But, you say it doesn't work, yet that it tests Ok, so I'm not sure I understand the complete scenario.

Comment: Okay, let me conclude it a bit better: Yes, it's a WinRT App and it IS possible to communicate with any host in the local network. But it IS NOT possible to communicate with another application on the same host. The app runs for my test in a VMWare-Virtual-Machine with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Right -- it's not possible unless you do "enterprise" deployment to communicate with another app on the same host when running WinRT apps currently.

Comment: I don't see any sense in this restriction. Do you have a tip how to pull data from localhost? My idea is to import data from metro app to a word-addin.

Comment: You can't do socket communication. It's a security feature that apps can't randomly communicate with localhost apps. They are sandboxed. Further, dependencies on other apps aren't allowed. There really aren't any good work arounds if you want real time.

Comment: It makes no sense anyway, but thank you very much for your help!